# Selinux: How to log/monitor all accesses to a file?

Tags: selinux

Does SELinux support monitoring accesses to an object type? I would like to log all instances where sensitive files are accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SELinux can be used to log accesses, not just *denied* accesses. See [this message](http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-selinux-list/2004-October/msg00125.html) for some details on how to do it. [This documentation](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/writing_SELinux_policy_guide/index.html) may also be useful.